# exceptions.TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'settings'

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu

I have downloaded the `distribute-crawler` from github. But I found that didn't work. It is giving:

```
unexpected keyword argument 'settings'
```

Anybody know this?

The full stack trace is as follows:

```
2017-03-31 15:43:43 [twisted] ERROR: Unhandled error in Deferred:
2017-03-31 15:43:43 [twisted] ERROR: Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 57, in run
    self.crawler_process.crawl(spname, **opts.spargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 163, in crawl
    return self._crawl(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 167, in _crawl
    d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1237, in unwindGenerator
    return _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred())
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1099, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 90, in crawl
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 72, in crawl
    self.engine = self._create_engine()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 97, in _create_engine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 70, in __init__
    self.scraper = Scraper(crawler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/core/scraper.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.itemproc = itemproc_cls.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 58, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 36, in from_settings
    mw = mwcls.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/pipelines/media.py", line 51, in from_crawler
    pipe = cls.from_settings(crawler.settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/pipelines/images.py", line 95, in from_settings
    return cls(store_uri, settings=settings)
exceptions.TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'settings'
```

Comment: Could you link the github repository please? This is probably an issue that you'll need to take up with the developer.

Comment: can you to specify the github repository url ? Thanks :)